# Set explicitly language for file, Appcode

Tags: appcode

Is it possible to set a specific language for a single file? Let's say, I want to treat all *.js files as *js, but this single one as React JSX.

I found File Types, but it sets all the files with the extension, what is not my intention

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You can use ⇧⌘A -> New Scratch File, create a scratch for the specific language and perform the editing, but next, you will need to copy contents to the actual file.

Comment: thank you for an answer; will leave it unanswered in case there other ways to do that